# UnicodeDecodeError on import of a .pyd file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've started to slowly dabble with the Python/C API and after much fiddling and finagling, I was able to build a spam.pyd file.

However, I must be missing something with this process and was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction. I thought that once spam.pyd was created, I could call it from Python via import spam. Is this true?

When I try this, I get the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "< pyshell#25 >", line 1, in <module>

    import spam

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 1: unexpected code byte
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? I am working with Python 3.1.2 on Windows XP. I compiled spam.c via the mingw32 compiler.

Thanks for reading this!

EDIT:

Well, it looks like the problem was that I had written the C code in an editor that saved the file with ANSI encoding. Strangely, if I retyped the code in Notepad, and saved the file with UTF8 encoding, I would get compile time errors complaining about invalid characters. When I used the built-in IDLE editor, everything worked fine. I was just following the example from the Python tutorial [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example).

**Is this an usual problem to have??**

Here is all the code that was used if it helps any:

```
#include < Python.h >

static PyObject *spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *command;
    int sts;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;
    sts = system(command);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}

static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
    {"system", spam_system, METH_VARARGS,
     "Execute a shell command."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef spammodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "spam",
    NULL,
    -1,
    SpamMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_spam(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&spammodule);
}
```

Comment: Well then, you'd better shows us the [relevant parts of the] source of spam.c. Is this the first Python extension module that you've written in C? What textbook or tutorial are you following?

Comment: yes, it is the first time that i've written a Python extension module. I'm just following the tutorial on the Python website. I updated my question with more (hopefully) relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say: *Well, it looks like the problem was that I had written the C code in an editor that saved the file with ANSI encoding.*

This is exceedingly unlikely. There are no non-ASCII characters visible in your published C source. If there were any, you would have got an error message from the C compiler (except maybe if it was in a string constant; I've never tried that).

You say: *Strangely, if I retyped the code in Notepad, and saved the file with UTF8 encoding, I would get compile time errors complaining about invalid characters.*

Not strangely. Notepad prepends a UTF-8 BOM. This means your C compiler was being presented with a source file which started with 3 bytes of junk. Don't use Notepad. Use a proper text editor.

The indications are that the problem is much more likely to be in your Python input. The default source-file encoding in Python 3 is UTF-8. Your file contains "byte 0x89" which is not a valid UTF-8 lead byte and which the Windows cp125X encodings map to `‰` alias U+2030 PER MILLE SIGN -- either you have this in a string constant or you've typed that by mistake for a `%` (PER CENT SIGN). However it's difficult to guess how you got the traceback that you did. Getting into an interpreter (e.g. IDLE) and typing `import spam` should NOT give you that traceback.

Comment: +1 thanks for the explanation. i tried saving the code in a very old version of microsoft visual studio and got the same traceback (the file compiled just fine) so it's still a bit of a mystery to me. when moving over to a better editor, these problems did go away.